# Angular2 multi component UI with routing

Tags: angular

What would be a good (best) structure for an Angular2 (beta3) app with routing when a parent/child multi component is required?

For individual tables I have the following structure:

[image: single table structure]

So in the AppComponent I have non-terminal routes to individual TableComponents with their own router for showing List or Detail. I can use router.navigate() and all works great.

But now I need to show parent/child tables on one page (with their own detail form) like this:

[image: Parent/Child UI]

I already have the components for both individual tables (only need to add some filtering code for showing the correct child records but that would not be a problem). I started out with a MultiComponent to hold both TableComponents. Now I'm stuck...

I can not have two router outlets like:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet> (for the parent component)
<router-outlet></router-outlet> (for the child component)
```

Did have a look at 'aux' but I don't think this is for my use case.

I can do this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet> //(with @RouteConfig for parent TableComponent)
<ListComponent></ListComponent> //(directive for child ListComponent)
```

This works almost. It shows the parent/child lists and the parent works as intended. But the child has no router so when firing an update/detail form, there is no router. I can show the update (detail) of the child list through the (one) router outlet but when doing a router.navigate() (for instance to navigate back to the list) I get a "...has no route config." error.

So what would be the right way to re-use existing table/detail components (having their own sub-router) with Angular2?

Answer (score 0):

After some further experimentation I got a satisfiable result. The structure looks similar to the single table component setup. The key was in the @RouteConfig.

[image: Combi structure]

So, the CombiListComponent combines the two table components using directives. The key however is in the @RouteConfig of the CombiComponent. Here separate routes are used for the two tables:

```
  {path:'/',    name: 'CombiList',   component: CombiListComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path:'/Table1/',    name: 'Table1List',   component: CombiListComponent},
  {path:'/Table2/',    name: 'Table2List',   component: CombiListComponent},
  {path:'/Table1/:id', name: 'Table1Detail', component: Table1DetailComponent},
  {path:'/Table1/new', name: 'NewTable1', component: Table1DetailComponent},
  {path:'/Table2/:id', name: 'Table2Detail', component: Table2DetailComponent},
  {path:'/Table2/new', name: 'NewTable2', component: Table2DetailComponent}
```